# Mongoose Populate() no entrega resultado buscado

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

estoy intentando realizar una consulta a mongo, pero el resultado que me entrega populate no es el buscado.
Actualmente tengo lo siguientes schema's

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let pokemonSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    nombre: String,
    habilidad: [{
        hab: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Habilidade'},
        oculta: Boolean
    }],
    tipos: [String],
    peso: Number,
    altura: Number,
    grupo_huevo: [String],
    especie: String,
    dex: Number
},
{
    versionKey: false
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Pokemon',pokemonSchema);
```

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let habilidadesSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    own: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Pokemon'
    }],
    nombre: String,
    descripcion: String
},
{
    versionKey: false
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Habilidade',habilidadesSchema);
```

```
Pokemon.find({})
        .populate({
            path: 'habilidad.hab'
        })
        .exec((err, pokemon) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            else if(!pokemon) return res.status(404).send({message:'Error 404'});
            else return res.status(200).send({pokemon});
        });
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo después de realizar la consulta anterior

```
{
    "pokemon":[{
        "tipos":["Planta","Veneno"],
        "grupo_huevo":["Monstruo","Planta"], 
        "_id":"5e57969ff7c5c81414bb5198", 
        "nombre":"Bulbasaur",
        "peso":6.9,
        "altura":0.7,
        "especie":"Semilla",
        "dex":1,
        "habilidad":[{
            "_id":"5e57969ff7c5c81414bb5199",
            "oculta":false}, 
           {"_id":"5e57969ff7c5c81414bb519a",
            "oculta":true
        }]
    }]
}
```

Como se puede ver, populate no realizó lo debido con el campo habilidad
Me gustaria saber si es algun tipo de error dado los modelos, si la consulta esta mal realizada, o como poder solucionar dicho problema.

Dado que soy estudiante tambien acepto cualquier consejo sobre el codigo, buenas practicas, etc.